# Problemas con la implementación del split() en jQuery

Tags: jquery

Quiero validar un correo utilizando split(). Es primera vez que lo utilizo y estuve viendo en vrias paginas como funciona y segun lo que aprendi, hice esta funcion. Puede que no lo este implementando de la manera correcta, pero la consola del navegador no me lanza ningun error. El problema que tengo es k m dice "correoSeparado[1] es invalido", pero no se como solucionarlo. les agradeceria mucho su ayuda. PD: Tengo k hacerlo con split() pq fue el requisito que me pidieron.

```
function validarCorreo(correo){
    var separadores = ['@','.'];
    var correoSeparado = correo.val().split(new RegExp(separadores.join('l'),'g'));

    if (!validarTexto(correoSeparado[0]) || correoSeparado[1] != "estudiantes" || correoSeparado[2] != "uci" || correoSeparado[3] != "cu") {
        alert (correoSeparado[1], correoSeparado[2], correoSeparado[3]);
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes anteponer \\ a los separadores, así

```
var separadores = ['\\@','\\.'];
```

Luego, el operador 'o' de una expresión regular es "|" y no "l"

```
var correoSeparado = correo.split(new RegExp(separadores.join('|'),'i'));
```

Espero que te ayude. Saludos.

Comment: Estabas en lo cierto. Ya funciona sin problema. Para ser la primera vez k lo uso, no tuve tantos errores. Lo k no entiendo pq en todas las pág k hablaba del tema, nadie ponía los \\ en los separadores. Por cierto k significa la 'i'? Yo puse una 'g' pq así salía en una pág y no sé si significado. Muchas gracias x ayudarme.

Comment: Fijate en este enlace [enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp). Mas específicamente el apartado de descripción, ahí aparece la explicación para el uso de los \ antislash. Saludos.